# Inserting data into two or more tables:

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have the following tables:

```
thread: id, title, content, created
thread_tags: tag_id, thread_id
tag: id, name
author_threads: thread_id, author_id
```

In order to create a thread all of these fields must be filled in (The ids are obviously automatically incremented). I know that I can use SQL TRANSACTIONS to make sure all of them are filled in or none, however how do I go about filling in tag_id, thread_id, author_id and thread_id (in author_threads) from the last sql statement? Without the transaction I would use mysqli_last_insert_id.

Also should I use `mysqli::multi_query`? Basically how do I go about making sure all these fields are filled in?

Oh, and I'm using PHP with MYSQL.

**EDIT:**

Would this work?

```
   $sql_thread = "START TRANSACTION;
                  INSERT INTO thread (title, content)
                  VALUES ('some title', 'some content')";

   #  this is normally a loop, as there are more than one tags:   
   $sql_tags = "INSERT INTO tag (name) 
               VALUES ('onetag')";


   #  normally I would check the return value
   mysqli_query($link, $sql_thread);

   #  get the thread id:
   $thread_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

   mysqli_query($link, $sql_tags);

   #  get the tag id:
   $tag_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

   #  insert into thread_tags:
   mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO thread_tags (thread_id, tag_id)  VALUES ($thread_id, $tag_id)");

   #  insert into author_threads, I already know author_id:
   mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO author_threads (author_id, thread_id)  VALUES ($author_id, $thread_id)
                        COMMIT;");
```

Comment: Why cannot you do it the same way via mysqli_insert_id()?

Comment: I think you're looking for `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

Comment: I want them all to be filled in, or none. Hence transactions?

Comment: Last_insert_id, yeah I meant to write that instead of insert_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you already know the answer: use `mysqli_insert_id()` or `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. You should have no problems using them with transactions:

- begin transaction
- insert row
- get last insert id
- insert row, using id for foreign link
- ...
- commit transaction

If something fails, rollback the transaction, and you will have nothing.

Comment: How would you use transactions with mysqli_insert_id()? Also I need to get thread_id twice, what would be the logic there?

Comment: The last insert id still works inside of transactions. Even though the data hasn't been committed yet, the current transaction can still access it. To use the thread id multiple times, just set it to some variable after creating the thread record (e.g., `$thread_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);`).

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to try. ;) You should separate the begin/commit into their own queries; I don't remember off hand which (if any) of the MySQL functions support multiple SQL commands per query.